# wget command with tor using authentification

Tags: authentication, double, wget, tor

i will explain you my problem...

Im explain...I want to download all a TOR website with a wget.
but the problem is when i go to the website i have a pop up tell me:

`enter username: USER / password: PASSWORD`

so i type the user and the password and now i can see the login page.

But on the index i need to enter my Username and my Password of my account. And after that, its done and im in.

Now, I want to wget the website so ive used:

`torsocks wget --user=USER --password=PASSWORD` (for the first authentification)`--keep-session-cookies --save-cookies cookies.txt --post-data 'user=myusername&password=mypassword'`(for login into the website)`-r http://website.onion/`

But when i start the command:

`torsocks wget --user=USER --password=PASSWORD --keep-session-cookies --save-cookies cookies.txt --post-data user=myusername&password=mypassword' -r http://website.onion/`

I've a error 403 : Forbidden.

i hope ive been clear and you've understand my problem, and find how can i use wget on onion website using 2 authentification, one when i go to the website(probably for verify if im human), and the second for login into my account and access to the website.

If anyone have an idea, or another method than wget he's welcome, 
Thanks.

Comment: look into selenium & ghostscript to automate this properly. also I believe curl might have this capability built-in instead of wget.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, can you try to write the command using curl please? with curl its possible to remplace a wget command?